# If Anything Equals NaN

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write something like:

```
 if( * === NaN){
          this = 0;  
        };
```

What I'm trying to do is catch any math or variables that calculate as NaN and make them equal to 0. I could write the same if statement for each time math is done but it would be messy and I was hoping there was a simple solution like this.

Comment: Nothing equals `NaN`. Even `NaN === NaN; //false`

Comment: Well, you would need to use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and you can't assign to `this`. `this = anything` is invalid.

Comment: You need to look at all the variables, there is no "everything"

Comment: As a shorthand you may be able to use `(varname || 0)`, as this will (among other things) keep numeric values as they are but replace `NaN` (falsy value) with `0`.

Comment: Hey Yury, that was a loose example to get the point across of the intention as I said. You could substitute: isNan(*anythingHere) == true

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, since as far as I know nothing is equal to NaN. However, you can take advantage of that and do:

```
if( * !== *){
      //code when * is NaN  
    };
```

And only a NaN will meet the condition. [I read this is safer than just to use isNaN()](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/interview-questions) .

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
function convertIfNaN (x) {
    if (isNaN(x))
        return 0;
    else
        return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isNaN function like so:

```
if (isNaN(x)) {
    // do something
}
```

The built in isNaN function will only check if the value can be coerced to a number. You can also write your own function to simply check for the value "NaN" like so:

```
function isNaN(x){
  return x !== x;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the closest to what I was looking to achieve. It appears the simple clever code option doesn't really fit the situation and I just did a copy paste of a small if statement to check each time the variable would be used before it was used. Thanks!